# Using range in zipWith also emits all items from range sequence before zipper function applied

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

The question is about RxJava2.

Noticed that zipping `Throwable` that comes from `retryWhen` with `range` emits all items from `Observable.range` before zipper function has been applied. Also, `range` emits sequence even if `zipWith` wasn't called. For example this source code

```
Observable.create<String> {
        println("subscribing")
        it.onError(RuntimeException("always fails"))
    }
    .retryWhen {
        it.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3).doOnNext { println("range $it") },
                BiFunction { t: Throwable, i: Int -> i })
                .flatMap {
                    System.out.println("delay retry by $it + second(s)")
                    Observable.timer(it.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                }
    }./*subscribe*/
```

gives the following result

```
 range 1
 range 2
 range 3
 subscribing
 delay retry by 1 + second(s)
 subscribing
 delay retry by 2 + second(s)
 subscribing
 delay retry by 3 + second(s)
 subscribing
 onComplete
```

Replacing `onError` in `observable` creation also don't eliminate emitting `range` items. So the question is why it's happening as `Range` is cold.

Comment: Because `flatMap` prefetches up to 128 elements (16 on mobile). Use `concatMap` or `flatMap(... , 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable`s in 2.x don't have backpressure thus a `range` operator will emit all its items as soon as it can. Your case, however, can use a normal counter incremented along the error notification of the retry handler:

```
source.retryWhen(e -> {
    int[] counter = { 0 };
    return e.takeWhile(v -> ++counter[0] < 4)
            .flatMap(v -> Observable.timer(counter[0], TimeUnit.SECONDS));
})
```